# C Compiler is generating errors when trying include C++ class header

Tags: c++, c

I am compiling C code using gcc ( C compiler (can't use C++) ) and one of the .c file includes a header (Monitor.h) which defines a C++ class Monitor. When I try to compile I am receiving the following error:-

In file included from /home/tp/workspace/gft/Display.h:39,
                 from **asr_iface_ctl.c**:29:

**/home/tp/workspace/pcd/Monitor.h:19: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '_*attribute*_' before 'Monitor'**

Following are some of the flags that I am passing to the compiler (Makefile):

```
COMPILE_LEVEL = -O3
OPTIONS       = -g -Wall $(COMPILE_LEVEL) -D_REENTRANT

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .cpp .c $(SUFFIXES)

TMP  = $(SRC:.c=.o)
OBJS = $(TMP:.cpp=.o)

.cpp.o:
    @echo "    Compiling  $<"
    @$(CPP) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

.c.o:
    @echo "    Compiling  $<"
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<
    @ar -rc $(LIB) $@
```

Is it OK to include C++ class header in a .c file ? If yes how can i resolve the above error ?

NOTE: I can't use C++ compiler.

Comment: You should examine the offending header-file, Monitor.h, and see if it has any options such as #define C_ONLY, or #define NO_CPLUSPLUS that would help.  (not likely... a long shot, but your best bet)

Comment: All you have to do is say this one out loud. "I can't use C++. I am trying to use a C++ class and include a C++ header."

Comment: why can't you use a c++ compiler ? D:

Comment: While I usually dislike users looking down their noses at questions they consider silly, this one makes me wonder if there should be a close reason "too silly".

Comment: @user1279025: You are misguided by the many mentionings of the word `C/C++` in the internet. There is no such language; while you can use most of C in C++ because C++ is designed to be compatible with most of C code, the opposite is not true. Note: **C is not C++, C++ is not C, however, C++ shares a subset with C (but _not_ vice versa).**

Comment: Although this seems too basic, I would be suprised if user1279025 is the first or last SO user to make this mistake.

Comment: @sbi: No there shouldn't. Remember that you started small, too. user1279025 is maybe just starting, and right his next big discovery will be "there is no C/C++", which is a valuable thing. He's trying out stuff that he hadn't been taught explicitly, which is a good thing in general. Don't discourage that by being snotty.

Answer (score 16):

No, you can't include C++ header in a C program. C++ is not C, and C compiler will not understand C++.

Comment: @MooingDuck: There's no "yes". It's impossible and not resolvable.

Answer (score 8):

All you have to do is say this one out loud. "I can't use C++. I am trying to use a C++ class and include a C++ header."

Answer (score 1):

You are misguided by the many mentionings of the word C/C++ in the internet. There is no such language; while you can use most of C in C++ because C++ is designed to be compatible with most of C code, the opposite is not true. Note: C is not C++, C++ is not C, however, C++ shares a subset with C.